# PHP Adodb Active Record SQL Injection

Tags: php, activerecord, adodb

I can't seem to ascertain whether or not the PHP Adodb Active Record, DB ORM secures against SQL Injection.

http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-active-record.htm

Specifically I am using the updating and inserting methods, e.g.:

```
$person = new person();
$person->name_first = $_POST['firstname'];
$person->name_last  = $_POST['surname'];
$person->save();
```

Do the $_POST variables need to be escaped?

Comment: I'm pretty sure such a high-level library will take care of sanitation itself. (I don't know for sure though.)

Comment: Well, that is what I would thought, but really need to know for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just looked through the code-- it does escape out the variables you pass. You can confirm this by turning on debug mode... or even easier, try writing out a string with single and double quotes and see if it makes it into the table okay :-)